# How to use a file modified by a R chunk in a Python one

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am working in Rmarkdown into primarily R chunks, which I used to modify data frames. Now that they are ready, a colleague gave me Python codes to process some of the data. But when transitioning from a R chunk to a Python one, the environment changes and I do not know how to use the previous files directly.

[image: R environment]
[image: Python environment]

> reticulate::repl_python()
>
> > > biodata_file = women_personal_data
> > > NameError: name 'women_personal_data' is not defined
>
> ```
> NameError: name 'women_personal_data' is not defined
> ```
>
> > > 

Ideally, I would like not to have to save the files on my computer between R and Python, and then back at R again, to avoid accumulating files that are not completely clean yet (because I figured it could be a solution).

I tried [this solution](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/language-engines.html#python) but seems to not work with Data Frames

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
biodata_file = r.women_personal_data
```

The '.r' makes it take it from R, because the variable was called

> r women_personal_data

[TIP](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/language-engines.html) = to come back to R, the variable is now called py$women_personal_data